# Django url path: capturing multiple values from url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

How do I capture multiple values from a URL in Django?

`Conditions`: I would like to capture ids from a URL. The ids vary in length (consist of numbers only), and there can be multiple ids in the URL. Check out the following two examples:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/library/check?id=53&id=1234`

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/library/check?id=4654789&id=54777&id=44`

The solution may include regex.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", view=my_view),
    path("<solution_comes_here>", view=check_view, name="check_view"),
]
```

P.S. all solutions I found on this platform and [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/) only explain cases for capturing single values from the URL

Comment: `path('check'`). The querystring is *not* part of the path. This can be determined with `request.GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', view=my_view),
    path('check/', view=check_view, name='check_view'),
]
```

Indeed, the querystring is *not* part of the path. This can be determined with `request.GET`. So you can obtain the ids with:

```
def check_view(request):
    ids = request.GET.getlist('id')  # ['3654789', '54777', '44']
    # …
```

There is however no *guarantee* that the `id`s will only be numerical, so you will need to validate that in the view itself.

Answer (score 2):

`request.GET` is a [Querydict.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) It has more methods than an ordinary dict.

What you want for this is `request.GET.getlist("id")` which will return a list of id values. `.get("id")` will return only the last of them.